# How to write a numeric value in an xml file when using XmlSerializer in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am creating an xml file in my android application using XmlSerializer. The code is as follows..

```
            serializer.setOutput(writer);
            serializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
            serializer.startTag("", "appointments");
            serializer.startTag("", "subject");
            serializer.text("test_subject");
            serializer.endTag("", "subject");
            serializer.startTag("", "location");
            serializer.text("test_location");
            serializer.endTag("", "location");

            serializer.endTag("", "appointments");
            serializer.endDocument();
            writer.toString();
```

here all the data i attached to the xml is string type. I want to add integer values also. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: Use Integer.toString() - what's the problem?

Comment: I want to get that value back as integer itself later from the xml file. Is it possible if I set the value as string here?

Comment: Late you can use Integer.valueOf(...some_string_representing_integer...)